# Weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, weblogic

I am developing a project which accesses the database, but I get this error:

```
Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1581339957215" for task "weblogic.deploy.configChangeTask.1". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is "loading a file that is related to the database"?

Comment: @f1sh developing a project which accesses the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your CLASSPATH with required version of log4j. The TRACE level is available in the log4j jar of version 1.2.12 or higher.